# file input into a struct struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, struct

I writing a program for school that needs to keep a calender of when assignments are due. I need to keep the course name (e.g. cs162), a description of the homework and a due date into an array of structs with a struct for the date within the first struct.

```
struct dueDate{
    int mm[2];
    int dd[2];
    int yyyy[4];
};

struct Task{
    char course[MAX_CAP];
    char description[MAX_CHAR];
    dueDate dueDate;
};
```

The first thing I need to do is read in any assignments that may already exist in from an already created file. The format of the file is this:

courseName; description; mm/dd/yyyy (dueDate).

Here is the load function (problem is after the strcpy's trying to get the int into the dueDate struct):

```
void loadDB(Task assignment[], int& size, char location[]){
    ifstream inTasks;
    char courseName[MAX_CAP];
    char fullDescription[MAX_CHAR];
    int mm;
    int dd;
    int yyyy;
    Task courseAssignment;

    cout << "inside" << endl;

    inTasks.open(location);
    while(!inTasks){
        cerr << "There is a problem with the path of the file " << location << "!";
        exit(1);
    }
    inTasks.get(courseName, MAX_CAP, ';');
    while(!inTasks.eof()){
        inTasks.ignore(MAX_CAP, ';');
        inTasks.get(fullDescription, MAX_CHAR, ';');
        inTasks.ignore(MAX_CHAR, ';');
        inTasks >> mm;
        inTasks.ignore(MAX_CAP, '/');
        inTasks >> dd;
        inTasks.ignore(MAX_CAP, '/');
        inTasks >> yyyy;
        inTasks.ignore(MAX_CAP, '\n');

        strcpy(courseAssignment.course, courseName);
        strcpy(courseAssignment.description, fullDescription);

        // PROBLEM
        // the warings are under the courseAssignment part
        // the error message is "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"
        courseAssignment.dueDate.mm = mm;
        courseAssignment.dueDate.dd = dd;
        courseAssignment.dueDate.yyyy = yyyy;

        addToDB(assignment, size, courseAssignment);

        inTasks.get(courseName, MAX_CAP, ';');
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not compiling in my gcc :( - error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[2]’ from type ‘int’
 courseAssignment.dueDate.mm=1;

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the declaration of the DueDate structure. You declare yyyy as an array of 4 ints, mm as an array of 2 ints and so on. And at the part of the code you pointed you are trying to copy an int over an array of ints, which is impossible.

If you eliminate the array declaration part from the struct, it should work perfectly.